# ArrayList of ArrayLists: How do I add a copy of the previous ArrayList and then append to it?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList (A) that contains another ArrayList (B). I'm trying to get A<sub>n-1</sub>'s B to A<sub>n</sub> and then add more to the list. An example:

```
list 0: a
list 1: a b
list 2: a b c
list 3: a b c d
```

What I have:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();

// ..
// main

    populate("b", 0);

// ..

static void populate(String last, int copy_index) {

    if(outer.size() == 0) {
        outer.add(inner);
        outer.get(0).add(last);
    } else {
        outer.add(inner);
        // add the copies
        int loop_count = outer.get(copy_index).size();
        int end = outer.size() - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < loop_count; i++) {
            String temp = outer.get(copy_index).get(i);
            outer.get(end).add(temp);
        }

        outer.get(end).add(last);
        System.out.println("list #" + end);
        for(int i = 0; i < outer.get(0).size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " " + outer.get(0).get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to append the original list (A<sub>0</sub>) and the new list (A<sub>n</sub>), where my lists will become:

```
list 0: a
~
list 0: a a b
list 1: a a b
```

I tried this with `outer.get(end).addAll(outer.get(copy_index))` and the same duplicate of list 0 and n occurs

Comment: I tried this with `outer.get(end).addAll(outer.get(copy_index))` and the same duplicate of list 0 and n occurs

Comment: The answer is in the question title. You need to make a copy. You're never doing any. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-

Comment: keep in mind that using structures like this is not very object oriented and it will add coding complexity. if you don't have a good reason to act like this consider to pass to a more OO design

Comment: I only have to run the code once, and it works for a simple explanation, but it hits an out of memory exception (C(64,32) > 2^30-1). Would moving to a more OO design fix this? Should I use a different data structure to make it more OO?